# Set date pattern in TextView

Tags: date, android-studio, kotlin

How to set date mask/pattern to `TextView` in Android Studio? Or should I use something else like plain text?
Date pattern: **YYYY-MM-DD**.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class:

```
public void formatAndUpdate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
    TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView.setText(date.toString());
}
```

Or:

```
public String formatDate(String formatString) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return String.valueOf(formatter.parse(formatString));
}
```